# Sorting city names fails

Tags: c, sorting

I want to sort the inputted city names but below code gives me such as:

İnput:

```
Newyork
Georgetown
Berlin
```

Output:

```
Berlin
Gewyork
Beorgetown
```

Why is that? I was thinking to compare with strcmp and swap the pointers then but it seeems it is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort(char *dummy);
void swap(char *first, char *second);

int i;
char *names[3];
char *temp;

int main(void) {
    //get the names of the cities
    puts("Enter names of cities");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        names[i]=malloc(100);
        fgets( names[i], 99, stdin);
    }

    //print entered names
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    sort(names);

    //print sorted names
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    getch();
}

//sorting function
void sort(char *dummy)
{
    for (i = 0; i &lt; 2; i++) {
        if (strcmp( &dummy[i], &dummy[i+1]) > 0) {
            swap(&dummy[i], &dummy[i+1]);
        }
    }
}

//swapping function
void swap(char *first, char *second)
{
    temp=second;
    second=first;
    first=temp;
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out the [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function.

Comment: Your sorting function is incorrect. Why aren't you using [`qsort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)?

Comment: Compile with the strictest level of warnings enabled (`-Wall` in gcc), and make sure that your program compiles warning-free. This wouldn't fix your logic, but the partial copying will be gone.

Comment: +1 for funny wrong output. ;-)

Comment: How does it even compile? On my machine, it throws errors. :(

Comment: I am using Visual stuido. Maybe I have to increase security level. It hinders my learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `swap` as

```
swap(&dummy[i], &dummy[i+1]);
```

your usage of the address-of operator actually makes a pointer to pointer to `char`. But the `swap` function expects a pointer to `char`, which makes the usage of the pointers in `swap` undefined behavior.

Change the `swap` function to have pointer-to-pointer as arguments and use the dereference operator `*` and it should work better:

```
void swap(char **first, char **second)
{
    char *tmp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}
```

---

Another problem is that you use the address-of operators on the pointers when calling `strcmp` as well. In that case you should *not* do it.

And a third problem is that you pass an array of pointers to the `sort` function which takes just a `char` pointer. Change prototype (and function) to

```
void sort(char *dummy[]);
```

It's amazing that this even compiles for you with all these problems. At the least you should be getting tons of warnings if not errors.

Answer (score 2):

You're swapping characters, not pointers. The prototype of you `sort` function is just as bad for pretty much the same reason.

**PS:** Bubble sort requires two nested loops, not just one.

If you're not trying to re-implement sorting for academic purposes and instead just want to get your sorting done, you should use `qsort` instead.

Otherwise, you have to correct your swap function, then your sort function.

Answer (score 1):

You need two `for` loops to `sort` not one. You need to modify prototypes in the functions.

One thing you need not to pass names to function when you declared in GLOBAL SCOPE.

> declare *names[3] inside main

**USE** this below **code**:

```
my_sort(names);
//function call 

//defination     
void my_sort(char *dummy[]){
int i,j;
char temp[100];
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
for(j=i+1;j<3;j++)
     {
       if (strcmp(dummy[i],dummy[j]) >0)
         {
         strcpy(temp,dummy[i]);
         strcpy(dummy[i],dummy[j]);
         strcpy(dummy[j],temp);
         }
     }
}
```

**OR**

```
void my_sort(char *dummy[])
{
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(j=i+1;j< 3;j++)
      if (strcmp(dummy[i],dummy[j]) >0)
          swap(&dummy[i],&dummy[j]);
}



void swap(char **first, char **second)
{
    char *tmp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}
```

Comment: So glad...take care while dealing with global and local. and also passing parameters by value and as well as reference. Happy coding..